# Converting String() to c_char array in Python

Tags: python, string, ctypes

I'm using ctypes in order send the request to C++ application. For this I created the same structure in Python and C header file like this

C

```
typedef struct {
   int msg_id;
   unsigned char name[20];
} c_struct;
```

Python

```
from ctypes import *

class py_struct(BigEndianStructure):
    def __init__(self):
        BigEndianStructure.__init__(self)

    _fields_ = [('msg_id', c_int), ('name', c_char*20)]


.....

self.name = StringVar()
Entry(self, textvariable=self.name)

.....

def send(self):
   cmd = py_struct()
   cmd.name = self.name.get()
```

It doesn't work and raises a TypeError exception.

another code also doesn't work for me
like this

```
name = (c_char*20)(self.name.get())
cmd.name = name
```

or

```
name = (c_char*20)(self.name.get().encode('utf-8'))
cmd.name = name
```

I've tried many ways to convert the Python string object with ctypes.

- ctypes.c_char_p
- ctypes.create_string_buffer

Can someone help me to convert a string object to c_char*20 array? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution

```
name = bytes(self.name.get().encode('utf-8'))
cmd.name = name
```

Comment: `.encode()` returns a bytes object and defaults to `utf-8` so `cmd.name = self.name.get().encode()` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reproducible example.  `.encode()` should be all that's needed:

```
from tkinter import *
from ctypes import *

class Demo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('name',c_char*20)]

root = Tk()
s = StringVar()
s.set('Hello, world!')

d = Demo()
d.name = s.get().encode()
print(d.name)
```

Output:

```
b'Hello, world!'
```